# Accessing SOAP client using Savon gem

Tags: ruby, ssl, soap, openssl, savon

I am trying to access a SOAP service using the Savon gem (http://savonrb.com/)

The SOAP service certificates for authentication.

I generated a certificate using openssl as follows:

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout name.pem -out name.pem`

The ruby code is as follows:

```
savonConfig = {
    :wsdl => 'http://www......?wsdl',
    :log_level => :debug,
    :log => true,
    :ssl_verify_mode => :client_once,
    ssl_version: :SSLv3,
    :ssl_cert_file => './name.pem',
    :ssl_cert_key_file => './name.pem',
    :ssl_cert_key_password => 'password',
    :open_timeout => 600,
    :read_timeout => 600
}
client = Savon.client savonConfig
response = client.call(:request_message, message: {})
```

When I try hit the SOAP service I get:

```
client.call(:get_something, message: {}): 
Savon::UnknownOperationError: Unable to find SOAP operation: :get_something
```

I have tried the same code with a SOAP service that does not require authentication and it works fine. So my assumption is that I have done something wrong with the certificate

I have combined the key and certificate into one, however when I split it out it still gives me this issue.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you double checked the WSDL you're using for that service? Try 'client.operations' and see what operations are listed for it.

Comment: I have and I get back the operations - which is what I am using. So the connection to the service is correct. I suspect must authentication is the issue at this point